# How do I load html page content inside of an HTML div using jQuery/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to load the contents of an html file (home.html) into a div container located inside of a main html file (index.html)after clicking on a link and I want to use jquery/ajax to do it. I have tried to find answers but have only come across answers pertaining to php and not html.

this is the html code I have so far:

> ```
>   <!-- navigation bar -->
>   <nav>
>     <ul>
>       <li><a href="#" data-target="home.html">HOME</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#" data-target="work.html">MY WORK</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#" data-target="about.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#" data-target="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#" data-target="contact.html">CONTACT ME</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </nav>
>
>   <!-- content div -->
>
>   <div id="content">
>
>   </div>
>
>   <!-- footer -->
>   <section>
>   </section>
>   <footer>
>     <p>Copyright &copy; 2017, All Rights Reserved</p>
>   </footer>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I'll take a look at it, thanks! :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading DIV content via ajax as HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715493/loading-div-content-via-ajax-as-html)

Comment: @JordiKroon How so? There's not even any asynchronous code in the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ajax stands for Async Javascript and XML. So TS clearly wants to load code from an asynchronous call.

Comment: @JordiKroon I'm well aware of what ajax means (having used it before it got that name). But that question is asking about how to return a response from an ajax call as the output of a function. This question is asking how to load HTML from a file into a document. The latter is a one-liner and doesn't require knowledge of the asynchronous nature of ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following; here you are getting the contents of `load.html` and putting it inside the `content` div.

```
    <!-- navigation bar -->
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" data-target="home.html">HOME</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-target="work.html">MY WORK</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-target="about.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-target="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-target="contact.html">CONTACT ME</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>

          <!-- content div -->

          <div id="content">

          </div>

          <!-- footer -->
          <section>
          </section>
          <footer>
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2017, All Rights Reserved</p>
          </footer>
        </div>

<script>
$( "#content" ).load( "/resources/load.html" );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery code could look like this:

```
$('a').each(function(b,c){     //loop through each a element
  $(c).on('click',function(){   //add click event listener
      var link = $(this).attr('data-target');  //get the link from attribute
      $('#content').load(link);    //load the link's content into container
  });
});
```

It will loop through all `a` elements and get the link from `data-target` attributes. Just remember to add jQuery to your webpage.